# flutter , Problema con un child , nose como definirlo

Tags: flutter

Tengo un problema a la hora de poner un child , nose como tengo que definirlo para que me lo acepte , ya que estoy llamando a otros widgets y necesito añadirle el column para que se agrupen en columna.

Gracias un saludo .

````
 @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp( 
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Scaffold( 
          body:_pageOptions[_selectedIndex],
          child:Column( //aki esta el problema
            children:<Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: 5,
                ),
                child: renderAppBar(),
              ),
              renderPata(),
              renderFoto(),
              renderIconos(),
              renderTexto(),

            ]
          ),

```
````

Comment: Hmm, no se entiende bien la pregunta, cual es el problema ? error? que es lo que muestra? que deseas mostrar? agrega una imagen de como se ve y como te gustaría que quede? cual es la duda?

Comment: La columna debería ir directamente en el body de Scaffold, ya que éste no tiene child. Después los children de la columna están correctos aparentemente, siempre que hayas definido esos widgets.

Comment: Te resultara util conocer un poco mas acerca de algunas de las propiedades del Scaffold, ademas de la [documentación](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html), te dejo un articulo que explica alguno de sus principales [componentes](https://medium.com/comunidad-flutter/flutter-widgets-08-scaffold-5455cd1714b5).

Comment: Hola buenas tardes. El problema es que estoy haciendo una navigationbutonbar para enlazar las diferentes pantallas de mi app, no deseo mostar nada el problema es que antes como dice javier tenia el column en el body pero para enlazar las diferentes pantallas de mi app ne cesito colocar esta linea   _pageOptions[_selectedIndex]  para poder poner  los enlaces alas panatallas, los widgest ya estan definidos , pero sin la linea que menciono no puedo enlazar las pantallas del navigationbuttonbar , pero el column necestio tenerlo tmb para el orden de los widgest que tengo ya definidos.